# Running a cron job with CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter

I need to run a cron job on a file using CodeIgniter but CodeIgniter won't let me run a file directly. i.e.

I can run the controller in the browser with:

```
api.example.com/index.php/cron
```

My hosting only lets me run PHP files and I can't do it via the command line because it won't let me run wget or curl.

How can I make CodeIgniter run a file like below:

```
api.example.com/index.php/application/controller/cron.php
```

I can call that file with my hosting.

Updated

Thought i would just update none of the options worked for me i ended up changing hosting and doing the following.

http://devsforrest.com/116/setup-a-cronjob-to-run-every-5-minute-on-media-temple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uset wget command along with your url to run cron in codeigniter file in your case it should be:

```
wget api.example.com/index.php/controller/function
```

and be careful do not use path of file use the url which invokes your function.

Comment: I have hosting with godaddy but this wget is not working. I tried multiple ways but no lcuk!

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for, or if I'm answering you wrong, but the way I run my CRON jobs with CodeIgniter is simply doing this as the cron:

```
php /path/to/index.php controller function
```

Then in the controller I have this at the top of it

```
if( PHP_SAPI != 'cli') exit('My Custom Error Message');
```

Comment: hi unlucky4ever still cant get this to work see how my cronjobs work in my image https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/isdcloud/backups/Screen+Shot+2012-07-13+at+09.42.33.png

Answer (score 1):

Here, you can find **Step by Step How To Setup Cron Jobs in CodeIgniter 4**,

**Step #1**

Installation via Composer

Open your project terminal and run this command.

```
$ composer require daycry/cronjob
```

**Step #2**

Package Configuration to Application

```
$ php spark cronjob:publish
```

Once, you will run that. It will publish a file with name **CronJob.php** inside **/app/Config** folder.

Execute migration command to run pending migrations of application:

```
$ php spark migrate -all
```

All done with the setup.

**Step #3**

Add Cron Job To CodeIgniter Task Scheduler

```php
<?php

namespace Config;

use CodeIgniter\Config\BaseConfig;
use Daycry\CronJob\Scheduler;

class CronJob extends \Daycry\CronJob\Config\CronJob
{
    //...
  
    //... other code stuff

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Cronjobs
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Register any tasks within this method for the application.
    | Called by the TaskRunner.
    |
    | @param Scheduler $schedule
    */
    public function init(Scheduler $schedule)
    {
        $schedule->url(base_url('cron/remove-users'))->named("RemoveUnverfiedUsers")->daily();
    }
}
```

**Step #4**

Enable CronJob For Tasks

```
$ php spark cronjob:enable
```

**Step #5**

Add CronJob Processor To Crontab

```
$ crontab -e
```

Add your job to run every minute.

Syntax:

```
* * * * * cd /path-to-your-project && php spark cronjob:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Example:

```
* * * * * cd /var/www/html/dev/codeigniter-4 && php spark cronjob:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

**Note:** Task scheduler will execute every minute but cron will run at the specified time period of once in a day.

Hope, this will help you to setup cron job in CI v4.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Cron extends CI_Controller {
    function index($dummy) {

        // Crony command

    }
}
```

Line: `api.example.com/index.php/cron/index/dummy.php`

Basicly given example uses the 3rd uri segment to pass a value ending on `.php` that you don't use.

Or else you can use good ol' [**Routing**](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html)

Comment: this wont work please see image attach https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/isdcloud/backups/Screen+Shot+2012-07-13+at+09.42.33.png

Comment: So basicly it fetches a list of all your php files in your ftp? What a complex and limited solution of them.

Comment: i know my hosting is so rubbish proper pain it wont let me run curl wget or anything icuk

Comment: I'd just create a simple php file that does a [`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) or cURL on the address you actually want to execute then.

Answer (score 0):

Use .htaccess to append .php to the requested URL, i did not test the code below, but i hope it helps.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [R=301]
```

Comment: hi rami still cant get this to work see how my cronjobs work in my image https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/isdcloud/backups/Screen+Shot+2012-07-13+at+09.42.33.png

Answer (score 0):

Use CURL and call your cronjob by URL. If CURL is enabled in your hosting that will be a good choice.

Create a PHP file name it cronjob.php in the root folder of your website and add the following script in a file.

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"http://www.mysite.com/index.php/controller/method");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$server_output = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
?>
```

Now in the cronjob call the php file cronjob.php and it should work.

Comment: hi nish still cant get this to work see how my cronjobs work in my image https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/isdcloud/backups/Screen+Shot+2012-07-13+at+09.42.33.png

Comment: Yes it is possible. I have edited the answer to explain it in more detail. Please check again.

Comment: doesn't work nish because i need it to run a .php file and not index.php

Comment: yes I understood the problem. Have you created a file named cronjob.php in your root folder with the above code? If so you can run cronjob.php file, and it will call the index.php with controller and method mentioned in that file. Isn't it?

Comment: hi nish if i try to run it http://api.example.com/cron.php i get Internal Server Error

Comment: Do you have CURL enabled in your hosting?

Answer (score 0):

simply

```
/usr/local/bin/php /home/cpanel_username/public_html/sub_folder/index.php param1 param2 optional_param3 optional_param3
```

Here

cpanel_username - username of your domain cpanel,

sub_folder(optional) - if your web application is any folder

Param(parameters) - refers to controller and their methods(functions)

Answer (score 0):

Codeigniter API Cronjob for godaddy hosting

CodeIgniter cron job API based daily 10 o clock

```
0   10  *   *   *   /usr/local/bin/php public_html/folder_name/index.php controller_name funcation_name
```

For Me Working Fine